# Call a "void" method that have values from another activity

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, pocketsphinx

Hi I'm quite new to Java, I wonder how to call a void method from another activity, when I already moved to new activity. For example, I want to call

> onCreate(Bundle state)

from `PocketSphinxActivty.java`
in my new activity `SMSReaderMain.java`

I already tried

```
PocketSphinxActivity ps = new PocketSphinxActivity();
ps.onCreate(null);
```

It gives no error, but when `SMSReaderMain.java` activity start it suddenly force close and not responding in the actual device.

I also try to change into `ps.onCreate(this)` or `ps.onCreate(SMSReaderMain.this)` but it gives

> The method setupRecognizer(File) in the type PocketSphinxActivity is not applicable for the arguments 
>    (SMSReaderMain)

Here's the complete code, and I want to call almost all of method there in my new activity `SMSReaderMain.java`

**PocketSphinxActivity.java**

```
package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements
    RecognitionListener {

//keyword yang digunakan dalem program untuk set ke even2 tertentu
private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
private static final String FORECAST_SEARCH = "forecast";
private static final String DIGITS_SEARCH = "drive mode";
private static final String MENU_SEARCH = "menu";
private static final String KEYPHRASE = "ok";

private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    // Buat nyiapin User Interface
    captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
    captions.put(MENU_SEARCH, R.string.menu_caption);
    //captions.put(DIGITS_SEARCH, R.string.digits_caption);
    captions.put(FORECAST_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
            .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

    // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
    // so we execute it in async task

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if (result != null) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                        .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
            } else {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

//nyocokin keyword dan pindah2 menu
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    try {
    Intent i= null;
    if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE)) {
        switchSearch(MENU_SEARCH);
    }
    if (text.equals(DIGITS_SEARCH)) {
        //panggil class SMSReaderMain
        recognizer.stop();
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SMSReaderMain.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if (text.equals(FORECAST_SEARCH)) {
        switchSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH);
    }
   //else
        //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

//nge pop up keyword yang sesuai kita ucapin sama library yg udah ada 
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
}

//kembali ke menu utama
/*@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    if (DIGITS_SEARCH.equals(recognizer.getSearchName())
            || FORECAST_SEARCH.equals(recognizer.getSearchName()))
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}**/

//nampilin caption yg di mau sesuai dengan keyword
public void switchSearch(String searchName) {
    recognizer.stop();
    recognizer.startListening(searchName);
    String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
}

//inisiasi recognizer di awal
public void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) {
    File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
    recognizer = defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
            .setDictionary(new File(modelsDir, "dict/cmu07a.dic"))
            .setRawLogDir(assetsDir).setKeywordThreshold(1e-20f)
            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    // Create keyword-activation search.
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

    // Create grammar-based searches.
    File menuGrammar = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/mulai.gram");
    recognizer.addGrammarSearch(MENU_SEARCH, menuGrammar);
    //File digitsGrammar = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/digits.gram");
    //recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);

    // Create language model search.
    File languageModel = new File(modelsDir, "lm/weather.dmp");
    recognizer.addNgramSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH, languageModel);
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

**SMSReaderMAin.java**

```
public class SMSReaderMain extends Activity {   

private final int CHECK_CODE = 0x1; 
private final int LONG_DURATION = 5000;
private final int SHORT_DURATION = 1200;

private Speaker speaker;    

private ToggleButton toggle;
private OnCheckedChangeListener toggleListener;

private TextView smsText;
private TextView smsSender; 
private BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //PocketSphinxActivity ps = new PocketSphinxActivity();
    //ps.setupRecognizer(null);
    //ps.onPartialResult(null);
    //ps.onResult(null);
    //ps.switchSearch(null);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_sms);          

    //recognizer.startListening(searchName);

    toggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.speechToggle);
    smsText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sms_text);
    smsSender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sms_sender);

    toggleListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                speaker.allow(true);
                speaker.speak(getString(R.string.start_speaking));
            }else{
                speaker.speak(getString(R.string.stop_speaking));
                speaker.allow(false);                   
            }
        }
    };      
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);

    checkTTS();
    initializeSMSReceiver();
    registerSMSReceiver();
}   

private void checkTTS(){
    Intent check = new Intent();
    check.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(check, CHECK_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == CHECK_CODE){
        if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS){
            speaker = new Speaker(this);
        }else {
            Intent install = new Intent();
            install.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(install);
        }
    }
}

private void initializeSMSReceiver(){
    smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(bundle!=null){
                Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
                    byte[] pdu = (byte[])pdus[i];
                    SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
                    String text = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    String sender = getContactName(message.getOriginatingAddress());
                    speaker.pause(LONG_DURATION);
                    speaker.speak("You have a new message from" + sender + "!");
                    speaker.pause(SHORT_DURATION);
                    speaker.speak(text);
                    smsSender.setText("Message from " + sender);
                    smsText.setText(text);
                }
            }

        }           
    };      
}

private void registerSMSReceiver() {    
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private String getContactName(String phone){
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    String projection[] = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);              
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getString(0);
    }else {
        return "unknown number";
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {    
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
    speaker.destroy();
 }

}
```

Comment: **never** call the Activity lifecycle methods manually.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really wrong approach to the way of programming in Android. Activities are one of the main core components in an Android application that is managed directly by the OS, which means that the system creates them and are managed by the OS. The onCreate method is part of the lifecycle and it is automatically called by the system. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) you have the activity's lifecycle.

The way of starting a new activity is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

As the activity is instanciated by the system, you cannot call directly to methods on it. The way of communicating between activities is by providing bundle objects in the intent, so in the new Activity you can get the data from:

```
getIntent().getExtras()
```

You can also provide backward information by using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`, receiving a result in `onActivityResult`.

You have the info you need [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: Okay, I'll try to figure it out first by reading the article.

Answer (score 1):

Activity corresponds to something you are going to display on screen. If you are not going to display anything, don't create activities.

In this example you do not need `PocketsphinxActivity` at all. You can move all the methods of `PocketsphinxActivity` into your `SMSReaderMain` activity.

If you want to separate speech recognition code into separate class you can create a separate `PocketsphinxRecognizer` class but inherit it from `Object`, not from the `Activity`.